# jQuery Form Steps with data-step

Tags: html, jquery, laravel

I'm having an issue with a function I wrote to handle form steps in my Laravel application using jQuery.

I have a modal with these different steps:

```
<div id="directional" data-step="1">
    <x-inspection.deficiency-directions/>
</div>


<div id="grounds-components-section" data-step="2">
    <x-inspection.grounds.components/>
</div>


<div id="grounds-deficiencies-section" data-step="3">
    <div id="yard-section" data-step="3-yard">
    </div>
    <div id="driveway-section" data-step="3-driveway">
        <x-inspection.grounds.driveway.deficiencies :driveway-type="$drivewayType"/>
        <x-inspection.grounds.driveway.deficiencies-2 />
    </div>
    <div id="walkway-section" data-step="3-walkway">
    </div>
    <div id="patio-section" data-step="3-patio">
    </div>
    <div id="deck-section" data-step="3-deck">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

For reference, here are the necessary parts of the components I've included in the above code:

```
<div id="driveway-type-section" data-step="driveway-1">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col">
            <h4 class="text-decoration-underline text-center">
                Driveway Type(s)
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 g-2 mb-3">
        @foreach ($drivewayType->options as $option)
        <div class="col">
            <button 
                class="btn btn-block btn-primary form-control btn-update-deficiency btn-text driveway-type-btn" data-deficiency-text="{{ strtolower($option->option_name) !== 'pavers' ? strtolower($option->option_name . ' driveway') : 'paver driveway' }}"  value="{{ strtolower($option->option_name) }}">{{ $option->option_name }} 
            </button>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" id="driveway-step1-back-btn" data-prev-step='2' data-next-step="driveway-2">Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="driveway-deficiency-section" data-step="driveway-2">
    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 g-2 mb-3">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="driveway-cracked" id="driveway-cracked" value="cracked" class="btn-check driveway-condition">
            <label for="driveway-cracked" class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control">Cracked</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="driveway-uneven" id="driveway-uneven" value="uneven" class="btn-check driveway-condition">
            <label for="driveway-uneven" class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control">Uneven</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="driveway-undulated" id="driveway-undulated" value="undulated" class="btn-check driveway-condition">
            <label for="driveway-undulated" class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control">Undulated</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" data-prev-step='driveway-1'>Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then I've got the jQuery function that handles the steps and sub-steps:

```
// Navigate to certain step in form
function navigateToStep(stepNumber, isSubStep = false) {
    // Hide all steps
    if (!isSubStep) {
        $('[data-step]').hide();
    }
    // Show the specified step
    $('[data-step="' + stepNumber + '"]').show();
}
```

And finally, the logic that handles the button clicks to call the function:

```
// Initialize to show step 1
navigateToStep(1);

// Handlers for Next and Back buttons
$('[data-next-step]').click(function() {
    var nextStep = $(this).data('next-step');
    navigateToStep(nextStep);
});
$('[data-prev-step]').click(function() {
    var prevStep = $(this).data('prev-step');
    navigateToStep(prevStep);
});

// Show driveway types
$('#grounds-driveway-btn').click(function() {
    navigateToStep(3);
    navigateToStep('3-driveway', true);
    navigateToStep('driveway-1', true);
    // I know this seems redundant, but it doesn't work unless I explicitly call each step.
});

// Show driveway deficiencies (step 2)
$('.driveway-type-btn').click(function() {
    console.log('Driveway type button was clicked');
    navigateToStep(3);
    navigateToStep('3-driveway', true);
    navigateToStep('driveway-2', true);
});
```

Everything is working perfectly fine until I try to navigate to the driveway-2 step. Initially I thought it was because the content was dynamically loaded, so I put it in a `$(document).on('click', '.driveway-type-btn', function(){});` block but it didn't change anything; and I'm still getting the `console.log()` the way it is now.

I just can't figure out what's stopping this from working, especially since I know the button click is working... any assistance would be greatly appreciated... I might just be getting crosseyed.

Comment: Probably should mention `Laravel` in the tags

Comment: Hi, what is `grounds-driveway-btn` here ? Also, how do you navigate from step-1 to step-2 is there some button can you add that as well in your asked question ?